# Send file by Ajax and FormData fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send a file using Ajax in Jquery creating a FormData previously. This is my code:

```
var inputFileImage = document.getElementById('uploadImage');
var file = inputFileImage.files[0];
var data = new FormData();                  
data.append('archivo',file);

jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/services/rpc.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {functionName: 'saveProfileImage', data : data},
    contentType:false,
    processData:false,
})
.done(function(response) {
    alert(response);            
}.bind(this))
.fail(function(response) {
     alert('Sorry, there was an unexpected error, please try again later.\n\nInformation about the error:\n'+response);
        });
```

This ajax always goes to the `fail` function, and if I change the `processData` to `true` returns my another error saying **Error: TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: archivo is the name of the DOMElelement which you are trying to retrieve the image?

Comment: you cant send additional info as json when you send a form data using ajax. we need to send it as a form field value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

processData has to be off to send binary data. The FormData element is completely used as binary data, while `data:{}` needs to be processed. Additional parameters have to be appended to the formData in this case!

```
var data = new FormData();                  
data.append('archivo',file);               
data.append('functionName','saveProfileImage');

jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/services/rpc.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: data,
    contentType:false,
    processData:false,
});
```